# SqlDateTime overflow exception in Entity Framework

Tags: entity-framework, ado.net

When calling `context.SaveChange()`, I get an exception: `{"An error occurred while updating the entries. See the InnerException for details."}` with an InnerException of `"SqlDateTime overflow. Must be between 1/1/1753 12:00:00 AM and 12/31/9999 11:59:59 PM."`

Generally this error is pretty easy to fix -- just find the DateTime property whose value was never set (defaulted to MinValue).  Unfortunately, I checked all properties on my object, and all of them are set to valid dates/times.

Is there some way to figure out which property EF is referring to when throwing this exception?

Also, I'm only actually checking the object I added to the context right before SaveChanges (and as far as I know, I'm only adding 1).  Is there a way to look at all pending data that is about to be saved?

**Edit**

InnerException.StackTrace:

```
at System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlDateTime.FromTimeSpan(TimeSpan value)
at System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlDateTime.FromDateTime(DateTime value)
at System.Data.SqlClient.MetaType.FromDateTime(DateTime dateTime, Byte cb)
at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.WriteValue(Object value, MetaType type, Byte scale, Int32 actualLength, Int32 encodingByteSize, Int32 offset, TdsParserStateObject stateObj)
at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TdsExecuteRPC(_SqlRPC[] rpcArray, Int32 timeout, Boolean inSchema, SqlNotificationRequest notificationRequest, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean isCommandProc)
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean async)
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method, DbAsyncResult result)
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method)
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior, String method)
at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
at System.Data.Common.DbCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
at System.Data.Mapping.Update.Internal.DynamicUpdateCommand.Execute(UpdateTranslator translator, EntityConnection connection, Dictionary`2 identifierValues, List`1 generatedValues)
at System.Data.Mapping.Update.Internal.UpdateTranslator.Update(IEntityStateManager stateManager, IEntityAdapter adapter)
```

**Edit 2**

It may have to do something with my work flow... For example...

- I build object SalaryInformation in the class responsible for building Entity objects
- SalaryInformation has an Employee property on it, but the class that builds it only knows the Employee ID, so it sets SalaryInformation.Employee = new Employee { ID = 1 } (leaving the date fields set to MinValue)
- I pass the SalaryInformation object into a method to be saved
- Inside the save method, I look up the Employee object in the database based on the ID and then assign the returned Employee object to SalaryInformation.Employee
- I then `context.AddToSalaryInformation(SalaryInformation)` and `context.SaveChanges()`

I suspect this is leaving a straggler Employee behind in the context with only the ID set, and no Dates, thus the error.

**Edit 3**

Indeed, workflow was the issue.  If I simply say `SalaryInformation.Employee = null;' before assigning the employee object from the database, then the straggler goes away, and no error occurs.

Is this the intended behavior and work around?  It seems quite terrible.

Comment: What is the stack trace on the inner exception?  That should give you a clue as to where to look...

Comment: Added the stack trace, however it's all very generic ADO.NET stuff.

Comment: It may have to do something with my work flow... I'm passing entity object `SalaryInformation` into a method.  SalaryInformation has an Employee property on it.  When passed in, .Employee is set to a new Employee but only the ID property is provided.  Inside my method, I query for the Employee by ID and re-assign SalaryInformation.Employee to the queried-for employee.  I suspect this is leaving a straggler Employee behind in the context with only the ID set, and no Dates, thus the error.

Comment: Have you tried to set SalaryInformation.Employee to an actual populated object instance rather than just setting the employee ID on the SalaryInformation object?

Comment: That's what I'm doing in the 4th bullet of Edit 2.  I query for the Employee and assign it to the property on SalaryInformation.  Once I assign the value there, it seems to connect the SalaryInformation object and all other properties to the graph (I don't even have to call context.AddToSalaryInformation).  So to get it to not error, I have to null out those fields that require lookup first before allowing anything to be attached to the graph.  It's not a problem to do this null workaround, it just seems silly.  I just want to use the entity objects as transport.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are setting the employee the wrong way. The simplest way to do this is:

```
SalaryInformation.Employee = context.Employees.Where(e => e.Id == 1).First();
context.AddToSalaryInformation(SalaryInformation);
```

That means a DB access.

In EF 4, with FK associations, you can do:

```
SalaryInformation.EmployeeId = 1;
context.AddToSalaryInformation(SalaryInformation);
```

In EF 1, a workaround is:

```
SalaryInformation.EmployeeReference.EntityKey = 
    new EntityKey("MyEntities.Employees", "Id", 1);
context.AddToSalaryInformation(SalaryInformation);
```

But creating a stub, like you do in your second example, [requires additional work](http://blogs.msdn.com/alexj/archive/2009/06/19/tip-26-how-to-avoid-database-queries-using-stub-entities.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

Use the SQL profiler tool and run a trace.

[Edit]
You can also try implementing EF tracing as described [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/jkowalski/archive/2009/06/11/tracing-and-caching-in-entity-framework-available-on-msdn-code-gallery.aspx).

Comment: I tried that, but only valid statements show up.  Is there some way to configure profiler to show errors?

Also, the exception's text leads me to believe that it never actually makes it to SQL.  I get "The conversion of a char data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range datetime value." from SQL when I tried to insert a bad date.", but perhaps ADO.NET captures an error code and provides a friendlier message.

Comment: Even if the datetime value is out of the acceptable range it would still be a valid SQL statement that should show up as prepared SQL statement with sp_execsql. Using a trace has worked for me before to diagnose these types of issues and I'm pretty sure the error must be coming from SQL server and not the provider. Try checking the SQL server error log too.

Comment: I think this is an ADO.NET error, not a SQL Server error. There *may* be a SQL statement associated, but it might have been successful.

Comment: Check my comment on the original question... I think that's my issue.  If I recreate the SalaryInformation object within the method, call AddToSalaryInformation, and SaveChanges, it works fine.  Why can't I use the existing object?

Comment: It's a bit more work, but try my suggestion of using EF tracing(link in my last answer post edit)

Comment: Hi James, I figured out the issue, but don't understand why it's designed like that.  Can you see Edit 2 and 3 above and offer any insight?  +1 for effort here (going to bookmark that link for later).